# Calculating Future Value w/user's input on principal, interest, and length

Tags: python, decimal, percentage

```
principal = float(input("Enter the initial principle: ")) #users input
years = int(input("Enter the number of years as a whole number: ")) #users input
apr = float(input("Enter the interest rate: ")) #users input

    principal = principal * (1.0+interest)
    principal = round(principal, 2)
print ("The value is: $",principal)
```

I do not know how to allow a user to input either a percentage or a decimal answer for the APR.  The furthest I made it involved the beginning of a loop with a .format which I didn't even know existed until a couple hours ago.The easy solution is just to tell them to use a decimal, but I'd like to incorporate something a little more complex (unfortunately too complex for me).
So can someone please explain how I can tell the program how to decipher between a decimal answer and percentage answer? And how to change the percentage answer into a decimal for calculations?

Comment: APR is Annual Percentage Rate?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python 3, then `input` returns a string. Instead of passing it directly to `float`, you could pass it to a function that looks for the percent sign, for instance

```
>>> def parse_decimal_or_percentage(s):
...     val = float(s.strip('%')) # strip any % symbols and convert to float
...     if s.endswith('%'): val /= 100.0 # divide by 100 if string ends with % symbol
...     return val
... 

>>> parse_decimal_or_percentage('0.11')
0.11
>>> parse_decimal_or_percentage('0.11%')
0.0011
>>> parse_decimal_or_percentage('11%')
0.11
```

If you're using Python 2, then you should be using `raw_input`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out in the morning. My brain is finished right now.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex:

```
import re

st=input('Enter decimal or percent:')   

m=re.match(r'\s*([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)(%)?', st)

if m:
    apr=float(m.group(1))
    if m.group(2):
        apr/=100.0
    print(apr)
```

If you enter `0.22` or `22%` or `.22` or `+22%`  etc etc it is parsed as the same float value of 0.22 after being fed to `float`. The presence of `%` divides by 100.0 to get the adjusted value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one, note that there is not check if the user enters invalid data.

```
interest = raw_input("Enter the interest rate: ") #users input
intr = 0.0

#check inf interest has %
if interest.endswith('%'):
    intr = float(interest[:-1])
else:
    intr = float(interest)

principal = principal * (1.0+intr)
```